# Is there a registry value for number of Windows Hello fingerprint sign-in attempts?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, fingerprint, windows-hello

The fingerprint reader on my Lenovo X1 Yoga is very poor, and often does not recognize me.  Since Windows Hello only allows 3 attempts, I often have to enter my PIN/Password instead.  Is there a registry value that I can change to increase the number of attempts I'm allowed?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no way to increase the number of attempts allowed.  You can either add additional fingerprints, so perhaps you can find one that is more accurate, or get a better biometric fingerprint reader that supports Windows Hello.

Comment: Bummer.  Surprised to hear that there isn't a value for that somewhere in the registry . . .Lots of people complaining of the low quality of the fingerprint readers on these machines, so it's not just mine.

Comment: Any source I have for the statement for there isn't a setting, but the fact there isn't a group policy, that indicates the amount of attempts speaks volume.

Comment: "it's hard coded into the loginui.exe process." >>>>>>>https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-how-to-set-number-of-attempts-for/b57a473b-7ec2-4aed-89b0-62ce4c1280b8